# Expo Go for React Native - QR Code Unscannable Due To Inverted Colors

Tags: android, iphone, react-native, expo, expo-go

I'm trying to learn how to use React Native to build apps with Expo Go.

When I create a new app and try to start it with command "npx expo start" (all within command line), it does generate a development server with a QR Code, but the QR code seems to have inverted colors and cannot be scanned by either an Android or iPhone.

I typed the development server address (exp://...) into the Android Expo Go app, and the above created app loads correctly. The iPhone Expo Go app doesn't have an option to manually enter the URL, so I'm stuck.

Is there any way to make the QR code work, or find a way to manually enter the development server URL into the iPhone Expo Go app?

I'm new to React Native or Expo Go, so please let me know if there's any explanation missing that I should include. Thank you!

Here's the screenshot:
[Expo Go with QR Code generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F71Zr.png)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into the same issue, try changing your terminal's font, that worked for me.